# Count unique count within groups and specific column in R

Tags: r, count

Hel lo I have a df such as :

```
Col1 Col2 Col3
Group1 Seq_1:Sp1 Prot_1A
Group1 Seq_1:Sp1 Prot_1B
Group1 Seq_1:Sp1 Prot_1B
Group1 Seq_1:Sp3 Prot_1C
Group2 Seq_1:Sp5 Prot_1E
Group2 Seq_2:Sp5 Prot_1F
Group2 Seq_1:Sp6 Prot_1G
Group3 Seq_1:Sp7 Prot_1H_AB
Group3 Seq_1:Sp7 Prot_1Y
```

and I would like grouby each group in Col1:
- count the mean number of different `Col3` values

for `Group1` there are `3` different `Col3 values`.
for `Group3` there are `2` different `Col3 values`.

- count the mean number of different `Col2 values`

for `Group1` there are `2` different `Col2 values`. 
for `Group3` there are `1` different `Col2 values`.
And store all the number for groups into :

```
 list_mean_nb_col2_values=c()
 list_mean_nb_col3_values=c()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `aggregate`

```
aggregate(Col3 ~ Col1, df1, FUN = function(x) mean(table(x)))
```

---

Or with `table`

```
rowMeans(table(df1[c('Col1', 'Col3')]))
```

Comment: I get the following message : ```Error in str_detect(value, "\\([+-]\\)") : 
  could not find function "str_detect"```

Comment: @Grendel is this related to this post.  I think it is on your other post